# I want to save a .png image from AndroidPlot

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, png, androidplot

I have written a code which plots a Line Graph.
This graph is plotted by using Android Plot..
How can i save this graph as .png image??

Answer (score 5):

```
        xyPlot.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        int width = xyPlot.getWidth();
        int height = xyPlot.getHeight();
        xyPlot.measure(width, height);
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(xyPlot.getDrawingCache());
        xyPlot.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fullFileName, true);
        bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the drawing cache of any View as a bitmap with:

```
Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
```

Then you can simply save the bitmap to a file with:

```
FileOutputStream fos = c.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
fos.close();
```

This example will save the bitmap to the local storage which is only accessible by your app. For more information about saving files check out the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Concise and straightforward answers like these are what make StackOverflow great :)

Comment: Worth noting that when compressing as PNG the quality value (90) will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Before call method `Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();` you have to call the method `view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)`.

Anyway it doesn't work on all Views, if your View extends SurfaceView the bitmap returned will be a black image. In that cases you have to use the method draw of your view [(link to another post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742868/android-creating-a-bitmap-with-surfaceview-content).

P.S.: slayton if I could write comments I would comment your post but I haven't got enought reputation

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in png format:

```
plot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.pot);
plot.layout(0, 0, 400, 200);

XYSeries series = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(array1),Arrays.asList(array2),"series");

            LineAndPointFormatter seriesFormat = new LineAndPointFormatter();
            seriesFormat.setPointLabelFormatter(new PointLabelFormatter());

            plot.addSeries(series, seriesFormat);

            plot.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/DCIM/img.png", true);

            plot.getDrawingCache().compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);

            fos.close();

            plot.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```